# Rails exclude folder from auto/eager load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, autoload, eager-loading

I want to scale separately some subparts of my rails app and avoid loading the whole codebase.

For the sake of example, let's consider an APIv1 vs an APIv2, but I'd also want to extend this any class/service in general

Is it possible to **exclude** a specific folder from the eager load (production) or autoload (in dev) ?

For example,

`api-v1-production`environment should exclude

```
controllers/api/v[^1]/**/*.rb
```

`api-v2-production`environment should exclude

```
controllers/api/v[^2]/**/*.rb
```

*I am writing [^x] as a convenient notation for everything but x) for the sake of example*

I know it is possible to **add** some autoload/eager load folders but what about excluding some instead ? (especially if they are inside `app/` which is autoloaded/eager loaded by default)

I want to avoid loading in memory too many classes/services, etc. that I know won't be useful

Answer (score 1):

I hope that 3 years later you may have already found the solution. Anyway...

You may try this:

- **api-v1-production**

Add this to your `config/environments/api-v1-production`:

```
config.eager_load_paths -= ["#{config.root}/app/controllers/api/v[^2]"]
```

- **api-v2-production**

Add this to your `config/environments/api-v2-production`:

```
config.eager_load_paths -= ["#{config.root}/app/controllers/api/v[^2]"]
```

Hope it works.